# Use 'el-get' to install 'jedi' for emacs on mac

Tags: emacs, virtualenv, jedi

When I use 'el.get' to install 'jedi', I get message:

'/bin/sh: virtualenv: command not found
make: *** [env/bin/activate] Error 127'

But I have already installed 'virtualenv', and when I type 'virtualenv' in the terminal, I actually get some description of usage of 'virtualenv'.

On the other hand, when I tried 'virtualenv' command in the shell-mode in emacs, it told me that such command cannot be found. I think this is where the bug lies.

Any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: Sounds like you're not setting `PATH` properly in emacs. Check your .bashrc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find where the `virtualenv` is installed (for example, by using the `which virtualenv` in the terminal), and add this directory to `PATH` inside emacs. You can do this with following code in your emacs init file:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":" "path-to-virtual-env"))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "path-to-virtual-env")
```

I personally use the following code to keep the `PATH` in Emacs synced with `PATH` in shell:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
    (let ((path-from-shell (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -c 'echo $PATH'")))
      (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
      (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
(when window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

Answer (score 1):

[exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) is another way to push environment variables into Emacs.